# Creating OpenCV project with no Video Transcoding (ffmpeg part) Support on Linux how to?

Tags: video, opencv, compilation, ffmpeg, cmake

Currently I use something like this to create project make files:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install-dir" -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -G "GCC"
```

And I use FFmpeg in my project that I compile sepratly. Also I do not like the way OpenCV workes with video transcoding any way - prefer to do it all manually with ffmpeg.

I wonder if it is possible to create project file using Cmake so that OpenCV **video** (not images like png, jpg, tiff, etc) transcoding part will not be compiled (**not camera grabbing - I like and use that one=)**)?

Comment: what do you mean video transcoding? ffmpeg is solely used for capture/video writing in OpenCV.

Comment: You cannot, and why you would do that? You need the whole ffmpeg library for video capture anyway. Just ignore there is an object there called VideoWriter. You won't reduce the library footprint with that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you would rather not have ffmpeg support with OpenCV, you can disable the WITH_FFMPEG option via the CMake GUI when you are building OpenCV. Or, if you can't use the GUI, you can do it from the command-line:

```
foo@bar:~/opencv-src/build> cmake -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF <many other options...> ..
```

You won't be able to capture from files anymore if you disable this option. However, I think if you have V4L2 support enabled, you can capture from the camera. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Hi, without `ffmpeg`, can `OpenCV` capture frames from all kinds of videos?

Comment: @Cupidvogel without the ffmpeg you can not save the video into disk